# Remember-me в Spring Security не работает

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, filter

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при попытке удаления JSESSIONID или перезапуске браузера, следующий запрос на сервер обнуляет remember-me Cookie и не подтверждает сессию.

```
        http
            .authenticationManager(authManager(http))
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/sendCode", "/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/*").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .formLogin().passwordParameter("code").usernameParameter("email")
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            }).failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .alwaysRemember(true)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(24*60*60*14)
            .key("Mykey");
    return http.build();

    @Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(){
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

При запросе по любому из путей авторизованного пользователя выдаётся 401 из exceptionHandling().
В заголовках ответа приходит два Set-Cookie подряд:

```
Set-Cookie: remember-me=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: remember-me=aFRLMWhLYkhmNzVLMWh6M2I0b2ZYQSUzRCUzRDo2Snd1ZWFkcTFZRGlzZXp4RjAwRHlBJTNEJTNE; Max-Age=1209600; Expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 23:40:17 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

В БД таблица есть и каждый раз создаётся новый токен remember-me:
[image: Токены в БД]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?
UPD: Под следующим запросом я имею в виду тот запрос, который происходит после удаления JSESSION куки. Без её удаления всё работает штатно.

Comment: У вас в заголовке куки пустое значение. Покажите каким образом вы создаёт эти заголовки.

Comment: Можно подробней, пожалуйста?

Comment: @RomanC
Если вы про Set-Cookie: remember-me=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/ , то этот заголовок Spring сам отправляет, я нигде это не указываю

Comment: `В заголовках ответа приходит два Set-Cookie подряд:

Set-Cookie: remember-me=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: remember-me=aFRLMWhLYkhmNzVLMWh6M2I0b2ZYQSUzRCUzRDo2Snd1ZWFkcTFZRGlzZXp4RjAwRHlBJTNEJTNE; Max-Age=1209600; Expires=Thu, 29-Jun-2023 23:40:17 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
` здесь пустое значение.

Comment: @RomanC
Как я уже описывал, до удаления сессии или перезапуске, remember-me не пустой. Он обнуляется как раз при последующем запросе, приходит как раз описанный вами пустой remember-me.

Comment: Если при последующем запросе происходит logout, то куки удаляются.

Comment: @RomanC не происходит. Запрос на получение данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась так:

`UserDetailsService` использует запрос к репозиторию, ищет пользователя по email. Spring передавал расшифрованный email правильно, но добавлял перенос строки.

Пока что заменил так:

```
repo.findByEmail(email.replaceAll("\n","")
```

После этого пользователь стал находится, сессия подтверждаться. Посмотрю откуда взялся перенос строк и, если что, дополню ответ.